# Can I have more voltage but ok wattage on a led strip?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led-strip

I have 1.2 meters of a 12V 14.4 W/M LED strip, I also have a 64V power supply with 300mA, a.k.a an 18W power supply. My question is if the 64V could damage the 12V strip even though amperage is low and the watt calculation is ok.

Comment: You can't change voltage without also changing current and therefore power. A constant-current supply is common with LED lighting, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're using. You may want to read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028

Comment: You CAN do this (I have an installation with dual 12V strips in series, which run on 24 volts. Worked 24x7 for 8 years so far. You would need 5 strips in series that are identical.     **However, 64 volts DC is dangerous stuff** and the electrical code is very stern about it. because it's so dangerous. Common 120VAC switches aren't good enough to switch it! Really.  It is very aggressive, for reasons.  **Do yourself a favor - toss that power supply and buy a ~12 volt supply**.  Insurance won't pay if you burn your house down with 64V DC.

Answer (score 1):

This will absolutely not work. It is liable to break the power supply, the LED strip, or both.

Assuming you have a constant-voltage power supply*, the power supply will try to output 64V no matter what, but it will be overloaded because the strip will take more than 300mA. Depending on the quality of the power supply, it will either turn off, or output a too low voltage, or break permanently, or catch fire.

If it doesn't turn off or output a too low voltage, then the actual voltage (before the power supply breaks) could be anywhere from 0V up to 64V, and if it's much higher than 12V, it could damage the LED strip as well.

For example using made-up numbers, some power supplies might be able to manage 24V 3A, but get very hot and melt if they supply that, which is why the label says 300mA maximum.

---

* Constant-voltage power supplies are the most common type, and the type that you want to use for these strips. However, there are also LED power supplies designed to output a constant current. If you have a constant-current power supply, it should say so. If you use a constant-current power supply rated for 64V 300mA, and assuming the voltage can go *low* enough as some of them have a minimum voltage, then nothing will blow up. It will output 300mA, the voltage will be quite low, and the LED strip won't be as bright as you'd like it to be.

---

P.S. You can calculate the nominal amperage of the strip by dividing watts by volts. 14.4W/m times 1.2m = 17.28W. 17.28W divided by 12V = 1.44 A. It's silly how they don't write the amps on the box.